# Product Saving takes more time in magento?

Tags: performance, magento, debugging

For saving a product it will more time in magento admin? How can i fix these issue please help me?

Comment: are you importing any products at the time of uploading. or are you reindexing ? do you have shared hosting ?

Comment: Backend functions run as fast as the resources allocated to Magento will allow, so unless you have a really buggy module, you need a better host that's been optimized to run Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities

1. Code quality
2. Hosting

You can check the first part by disabling all your third party modules. For second part test your store with another host.